# 500 server error when installing xdebug

Tags: php, centos, xdebug, plesk

I have installed Xdebug as per the wizard's instructions using my `phpinfo()` info, but when I add `zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so` to `php.ini` I get a 500 server error. I also tried adding the line through Plesk's UI on the PHP settings page, with the same effect. Every other step up to that point works fine; as far as I can tell xdebug is installed correctly.

Comment: What if run php from command-line?

Comment: Is that installation on your system or remote shared host? if it's on a remote shared server, have you asked the support service?

Comment: It's a dedicated remote server.